# How to use dynamic table in SQL query "Select * From $var; " $var is fetching from another file

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In below code i want to use $var as tablename, and the vale for $var is coming from another file. $var value is the name of table. So i want the dynamic tablenaame in sql query. but when i am executing following code then sql query is not taking $var value. But when i am declaring $var value in this file as static value then it is executing correctly. so please help me ...how to use variable as tablename in sql query.

```
include_once("set_team.php");
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


ob_start();
echo $table;
$var = ob_get_clean();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $var";
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$result = array();


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('name'=>$row[1]
));
}
        echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));


$conn->close();
```

Comment: what's in the ob_get_clean()?

Comment: if you print $var what's the actual value?

Comment: dynamic value you should not pass directly in to the query..It will cause security problem.The dynamic value you can get like $_POST['var'].If exist then execute query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can dynamically select tables in sql. You would have to pass the variable and then use it. Php provides Variable interpolation, which I find easier to both write and read, hence you can directly insert the $var_value within the string.

you can try Methods such as sessions, cookies, GET, POST variables.

**Session:**

```
//On page 1
$_SESSION['varname'] = $var_value;

//On page 2
$var_value = $_SESSION['varname'];
$sql_query = "select * from $var_value";
```

Run the `session_start()` statement on both these pages before you try to access the `$_SESSION` array, and also before any output is sent to the browser.

**Cookie:**

```
//One page 1
$_COOKIE['varname'] = $var_value;

//On page 2
$var_value = $_COOKIE['varname'];
$sql_query = "select * from $var_value";
```

The big difference between sessions and cookies are that the value of the variable will be stored on the server if you're using sessions, and on the client if you're using cookies.

**GET and POST**

You can add the variable in the link to the next page:

```
$var_value = $_POST['varname'];
$sql_query = "select * from $var_value";

        or

$var_value = $_GET['varname'];
$sql_query = "select * from $var_value";
```

This will create a POST/ GET variable.